# Train Stations Open Source Point Data

Tags: data-request, geospatial, openstreetmap

I am searching for proper open source train station data.

I need only the central stations per country (best would be worldwide). I know the OSM source stations for each country but as far as I know you can't differentiate between the station type.

The values I'm looking for are `name`, `country`, `longitude` and `latitude`.

Is there any reliable source?

Comment: you've tagged openstreetmap is that not your answer?

Comment: Could you give a bit more detail on how you want to use the data, how reliable the data needs to be, how up to date the data needs to be, etc ...

Comment: I need only the central stations per country (best would be worldwide). I know the OSM source stations for each country but as far as I know you can't differentiate beetween the station type.

Answer (score 2):

I can only validate this method for Germany and by using [QGis 2.14](http://www.qgis.org/de/site/) but here my result:

- [Download the OSM data](http://download.geofabrik.de/) of the country of your choice (I used Germany) and look for  `osm_transport.shp`.
- Select the `train_station`s from fclass attribute (this can also be the last step) with `"fclass" = 'railway_station'`
- run multiple selections with this expression: `"name" LIKE '%Hauptbahnhof%'` and `"name" LIKE '%Hbf%'` and create new shapefiles or merge the selections
- The result will be all stations which are named "Hauptbahnhof"/"Hbf" of germany
- repeat those steps for your country. I am not sure if this will yield all results especialy because I dont know how naming is handled in other countrys

Let me know if you need further explainations

Comment: Yes that's what Ich did in pgAdmin but for other countries this will be hard because they are tagged only with station. In London for example there are more than 40 stations but no string with the explanation central station.

Comment: [This article from the guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/news/datablog/2011/may/19/train-stations-listed-rail) covers visitor per train station in the UK. maybe you wont get all central stations but the most important ones. [Here you can download the data they used](https://www.theguardian.com/news/datablog/2011/may/19/train-stations-listed-rail#data)